# How to improve readability of this assignation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to improve the readability of this code? The dataframe (`df`) is created in order to save this information:

```
   for idx, elem in enumerate(list):
        df.loc[idx, 'model'], df.loc[idx, 'param'], df.loc[idx, 'pre'], df.loc[idx, 'red_dim'], df.loc[idx, 'lv_sel'] = elem.split('-')
```

Comment: Do you mean "*assignment* [code]"?

Comment: @usr2564301 Conceptually it's a better fit there, but this is far from complete runnable code.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: technically, [graphicdesign.se] might also fit! (I.e., "Use a larger font", "make the lines not longer than ~60 characters"...)

Comment: @usr2564301 Thanks for your suggestion. The next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass multiple columns to [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
cols = ['model', 'param', 'pre', 'red_dim', 'lv_sel']
df.loc[idx, cols] = elem.split('-')
```

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

Comment: @AntonioAndrés This will create an empty data frame. Not sure why I should add it to the answer as your question was strictly about the assignment itself. Can you explain more?

Comment: You should define previously the columns of dataset:
KeyError: "['model' 'param' 'pre' 'red_dim' 'lv_sel'] not in index".
Maybe, I should be more detailed in my explanation in the original post

Comment: Better state that in your question next time ;)